# Optional in-tree builds for dependencies

Tags: cmake, git-submodules

I have an existing codebase where a number of third-party dependencies were added as Git submodules, and their directories are directly referenced inside CMakeLists.txt, as in `include_directories(../external/foo)`.

Some of the dependencies are large projects, like FFmpeg, and I'd rather just use the version I installed to my system with a package manager. But the maintainer of the codebase wants to be able to continue using the in-tree dependencies.

I thought a compromise would be to configure CMake to permit both, either using an installed package, or using the in-tree submodules. I think `find_package` can be used to find the installed package, but is there a good way to implement this behavior that isn't too hacky?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option to your cmake file that allows the user to switch between the internal FFMpeg or the system one. option(INTREE_FFMPEG "Use the intree ffmpeg" ON). The option can be set either via the cmake-gui or as a command line switch.